# Extraer variable de un resultado de ios_commans

Tags: ansible

tengo la tarea

- name:
  ios_command:
  authorize: no
  commands: sh mac add | inc 8d59
  register: hc
- debug:
  msg:

  - "{{ hc.stdout_lines }}"

el resultado es

"* 763      ace2.d311.8d59    dynamic     ~~~      F    F  Po111"

desearia extraer unicamente la interfaz "Po111"

Answer (score 0):

Con esto deberías obtener los últimos 5 caracteres:

```
msg: "{{ hc.stdout_lines[hc.stdout_lines|length-5:] }}"
```

Pero hay que tener encuenta que para que esto sea válido has de saber que siempre son 5 caracteres, aún asó podrías adaptarlo para que encage en la lógica general que buscas.

Mi prueba ha sido la siguiente:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  vars:
    - prueba: "* 763 ace2.d311.8d59 dynamic ~~~ F F Po111"
  tasks:
    - debug: msg="{{ prueba[prueba|length-5:] }}"
```